# Reloading of primefaces files in tomcat with Intellij IDEA

Tags: java, tomcat, primefaces, intellij-idea, tomcat7

So I'm developing a Java application which has a Primefaces front-end. When I used Spring Tool Suite and started the project in tomcat I was able to edit the front-end xhtml files and they got reloaded on the webserver.

Now I've setup my Intellij IDEA to run my project in a tomcat, but I can't get my front-end files to be reloaded other than restarting the server.

Any advice on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actaully had to edit the Run Configuration and change `On frame deactivation` to `Updated classes and resources`

Answer (score 0):

You have to use "Package File" option (or Ctrl+Mayus+F9) when you have edited the xhtml or modified classes.

You can also use "Update" option (or Ctrl + F10) and select "Update resources" or "Update classes and resources".